# Existing light switch need to convert to always hot

Tags: electrical

I have an existing driveway switched light, im planning on adding an outdoor outlet for when i need to xmas decorate. Can i do a pigtail at the light socket end and add an outlet but the outlet needs to be independent of the switch and is ALWAYS hot??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only if the switch is a switch loop.  Main power is at the light junction and only the hot goes to the switch and back to light.  Remove switch cover and see if only two wires(one cable +ground) are there.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will open it and take a snapshot this Saturday. My son is graduating college and is scheduled to march to morrow ( 12/17) and we’ve been preparing the past few days for it. I will post on here ASAP. Happy weekend everyone!!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how it is wired.  If the power goes to the junction box at the light, then one single cable takes the power down to the switch and returns from the switch -- this is called a switch leg.  Hooking up a receptacle up there would be easy (a pigtail like you mention can work).

If the power goes to the switch, then a new cable would need to be pulled, and in most cases a new circuit can be easier -- as you may end up opening walls to pull the cable up from the switch.

Comment: Briefly, if only two wires in box, answer no.

Comment: @user262983 , you missed the part about a new cable many home owners want this over a new circuit, it is still a possibility just not with a pigtail.

Comment: You guys are all awesome! I now have better understanding of what im trying to accomplish. Will update as soon as we get our diploma. Happy weekend!!